# values not returned as it should in a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a simple PostgreSQL query on the following table named storelocation2:

```
store_name   | brand  | city   | store_id
----------------------------------------------
MS Products  | SAMSUNG|Gurugram|5611
Ajay Electric| SAMSUNG|Gurugram|5611
Vijay Sales  | SAMSUNG|Gurugram|5611
```

Upon running this command:

```
postgres=> \d storelocation2;
```

the following table details are returned:

```
   Column    |         Type          | Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------+-----------
store_name   | character varying(20) |
brand        | character varying(20) |
city         | character varying(20) |
store_id     | numeric               |
```

**Query**
Now when I run the select statement:

```
select city 
from storelocation2 where 
brand='SAMSUNG';
```

following results:

```
city
------
(0 rows)
```

which is wrong.

Comment: Maybe trailing or leading whitespaces. Try `where trim(brand) = 'SAMSUNG'`

Comment: dude add it as an answer, worked like charm...

Comment: Use `LIKE '%SAMSUNG%'` insetead of 'pure' equality so if there is some spaces after or before will match anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that what you see as `SAMSUNG` is not what you get.  This is normally due to unexpected characters at the beginning or end of the string.

The most common would be spaces, which are handled with:

```
where trim(brand)= 'SAMSUNG'
```

Next are other hidden characters, which you can find with:

```
where brand like '%SAMSUNG%'
```

Then there are characters "in-between":

```
where brand ~ '.*S.*A.*M.*S.*U.*N.*G.*'
```

Depending on which of these end up matching, you can investigate the unusual characters in the column.

Answer (score 0):

try like below by uisng `trim` function though already it said in comments

```
select city 
from storelocation2 where 
trim(brand)='SAMSUNG';
```